# Grails 2.3.8 function being called by itself?

Tags: grails

I have this grails function in my controller:

```
def remediationSearch() {
        def resultList
        if (params.rerender) {
            println "<><><> remediationsearch called with rerender."
            resultList = recordSearchService.individualSearch(session.oldIndRemedParams)
        }
        else {
            params.selectedBatch = selectedBatch
            session.oldIndRemedParams = params
            resultList = recordSearchService.individualSearch(params)
            println "<><><> remediationsearch called fresh."
        }
        render(template: 'indivSearchResults', model: [resultList: resultList, resultCount: resultList?.size()])
        println "<><><> remediationsearch done at " + new Date()
    }
```

which seems to get called when I call this method(in the same controller) which has nothing to do with it:

```
def chooseupload = {
        println "<><><> Begin choose/upload at: " + System.nanoTime()
        if (session.user == null) {
            render(contentType: 'text/json') {
                [success: true, url: createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'logout')]
            }
        }
        else {
            selectedBatch = null
            def batchList = (Batch.findAllWhere(userId: session.user.id.toLong(), [sort: "lastUpdate", order: "desc"]))
            render(template: 'chooseupload', model:  [batchList: batchList, batchCount: batchList.size()])
        }
        println "<><><> End choose/upload at: " + System.nanoTime()
    }
```

The second method finishes executing and then the first one gets called for a reason I don't understand.
Is it(the first function) being called by some browser mechanism that is being invoked because it stores things in the session? I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction. I get this printed as a result of calling the 'chooseupload' method:

```
<><><> Begin choose/upload at: 446158993759810
<><><> End choose/upload at: 446159022252873
<><><> Begin remediationSearch at: 446159080286132
<><><> Rerender call to entityRemediationSearch.
<><><> End remediationSearch at: 446159135646835
```

So what is happening is that the `chooseupload` function's template renders but it is immediately rendered over by the template rendered by the `remediationSearch()` function. And that is the undesired result that led me to investigate this whole thing.

Comment: Does it continue to do so if you change `def chooseupload = {` to `def chooseupload() {`?

Comment: @Joshua Moore Yes it still does it. That does not change anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: print lines `Begin entityRemediationSearch at: 446159080286132` and below is not part of `remediationSearch()` as far as I see.

Comment: It's not clear what's going on, but only methods that correspond to request urls should be public - if you have helper methods that are only called from inside the controller, make them private or proptectedm both to be self-documenting as non-action methods, and to guard against being externally called.

Comment: @Burt Beckwith I tried privacy with both of them but I lose other desired behavior. When `remediationSearch()` gets called unnecessarily. It is right after I call another function which renders a template in the same area, that function is `choose/Upload` both of these are the two functions above.

Comment: @Burt Beckwith I have another function very similar to `remediationSearch()` called `entityRemediationSearch()` which also gets called unnecessarily at times. I am trying to find the commonality between why this is happening. I thought there is some mechanism in the browser regarding the session that I don't understand.

Comment: The unnecessary calls seem to happen right after I call another function which renders some template.

Comment: One trick I use to see where a method is being called from is to add `new Exception("why are you calling me?!?!").printStackTrace()` at the top

Comment: @BurtBeckwith As a Grails newbie, I wondered if such a mechanism existed and how to use it. Thanks so much. So this would go at the top of the suspect method which seems to be getting called for no apparent reason?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Ok that printed out a bunch of stuff which I can't paste here it's too long for a comment and I am trying to decipher it. I might post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this makes more sense as a comment or answer, but I don't have the 50 reputation needed to make a comment, so here it is as an answer :-)

I noticed that in your text output you have the line:

`<><><> Rerender call to entityRemediationSearch.`

But that is not included in the code you provided. Would it be possible that you're using an IDE that has not properly cleaned out old versions of the class files? Did `chooseupload()` call `remediationSearch()` at one point in time? If so, it seems like it would be good to try running this from the command line, after running `grails clean`.